# Section alpha and Wing alpha are same or different?

Tags: aerodynamics

What is the difference between Section alpha and Wing alpha?
Are they the same or different?

Comment: What are you talking about? Alpha angle? Please provide a clear context for the question.

Comment: More information needed here.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the reference. The section alpha is for the wing section and measured against the airfoil chord, the connection between the center of the nose radius and the trailing edge.

The wing alpha is measured against an arbitrarily defined reference which might or might not coincide with the section alpha of the wing airfoil. Most wings have washout or airfoil variations over span, so the local section alpha and the wing alpha will coincide at most over some part of the wing only.